# Differential form for two variable function where lower and the variable are the same

Tags: stochastic-calculus, differential-forms

The attached page is from Steven Shreve's Stochastic calculus.

In the attached page, there is a differential form for a definite integral with two variables: $t$ and $v$'. Integrable variable is $v$ since the integrator is $dv$:

$$
d\left(-\int_t^Tf(t,v)\,dv\right)=f(t,t)\,dt-\int_t^Tdf(t,v)\,dv
$$

I am aware how to find differential form for an integral where the limits and the variables are different.

Here the lower limit matches with one of the variables. Hence I struggle to find how the RHS has been derived.

I am happy even if the approach is detailed to me.

Thank you

[Differential form two variable integrable function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wFcX.jpg)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Ok thank you. Can I write the integral into the post area? Kindly advice

Comment: I have done it.

Comment: Thank you , but how do it from next time. Kindly forward me the link which will give guidance and I can do it myself next time onwards

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: A general question, is there a way I can seek an experts/users attention by forwarding their link. This thought primarily arising in case we have a urgent clarification required. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> The usual method is to introduce a function of two variables, say$$I(s, t) = -\int_{s}^{T} f(t, v)\, dv,$$then to differentiate $J(t) := I(t, t)$ using the chain rule. Leaving the details to you as a worthwhile exercise.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. Do you think there will be any reference material online to explain further the steps. I am an accountant by background. But I have taken interest in maths and doing learning with a phd student. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

This can be seen using [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Let $F(t)=-\int_t^T f(t,v)\, dv=\int_T^t f(t,v)\, dv$.

Applying Leibniz integral rule, we get

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dF}{dt}&=f(t,t)+\int_T^t\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,v)\,dv\\
&=f(t,t)-\int_t^T\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,v)\, dv
\end{align}$$

Note that the book is using the notation that "here and elsewhere in this section, $d$ indicates the differential with respect to
the variable $t$" (Section 10.3.2, pg 425).

Converting to differential form, we get the book's result:

$$dF = f(t,t)\,dt-\int_t^Tdf(t,v)\,dv$$

Comment: Superb. My PhD sir is thank you for the brilliant response and I thank you too. Your response can be chosen as the most suitable answer to my OP. Thank you once again. Is there a way you can help me on the other posts I have posted? Thank you once again.